# What is the meaning of "Pat came the reply"

Tags: phrase-meaning, subcontinental-english, non-standard

I was reading following text from a [blog post](https://urduwallahs.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/ghalib2.pdf) and I experienced difficulty  understanding the phrase - "Pat came the reply".  I've searched enough (limited to internet search engine) but I didn't find the standard or proper meaning (Suppose, I guess) of this phrase - Pat came the reply.

> Emperor Bahadur Shah Zafar asked him:
>
> "Mirza, kitne rozey rakhkhey?" ("Mirza, how many days did you fast?")
>
> Pat came the reply: "Bas huzoor, ek nahin rakhkha" ("Sir, I did not fast for one day")

I've also found the use of the same phrase in a book authored by noted Indian author and journalist Khushwant Singh - [K. Singh Best Indian Short Stories-Vol.II](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=xzC6VzGbt_EC&pg=PT6&lpg=PT6&dq=What%20is%20it%20%22pat%20came%20the%20reply%22&source=bl&ots=NNVWLKehnw&sig=Pd9ISRt1cIhHHaMSNLlF7gtKIz4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVnJmm2PbJAhWKBo4KHd1qBs4Q6AEIQDAJ#v=onepage&q=pat%20came%20the%20reply&f=false).

> 'No, bothersome. One can't spit.'
>
> Pat came the reply from Namu: 'Right
>   under the chair. Maaro pichkri!'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IMHO, this **pat** could mean "[in a pat manner](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pat)". From the Merriam-Webster dictionary:

> **[pat](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pat)**: in a pat manner :  aptly, perfectly
>   *'She has her part down **pat**'*

To paraphrase,

> Mirza replied *aptly*: "Bas huzoor, ek nahin rakhkha" ("Sir, I did not fast for one day")

Or

> Mirza came up with a *pat reply*: "Bas huzoor, ek nahin rakhkha" ("Sir, I did not fast for one day")

---

Alternatively, it could be an [onomatopoeic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) "**pat**". It's as if the reply *fell* with a sound that could be reproduced as "pat!" Compare: "plop!"; "bam!"; "cling!"; "clang!", etc.

---

I favor the first version: I googled for "came the reply", and found sentences where the word preceding "came the reply" is clearly an adjective, not an onomatopoeic word:

> Speaking about the lessons he learnt from the event in Bangkok, prompt came the reply, "I learnt never to be overconfident at any point." ([Deccan Chronicle](http://www.deccanchronicle.com/150907/sports-other-sports/article/i-was-overconfident-about-result-i-thought-he-nothing-vikas))

---

P.S.

From the grammar standpoint, the word **pat** in your sentences could be analyzed as an adverb. Alternatively, it could be analyzed as an adjective that is part of a *[secondary predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_predicate)*. That's my guess. I could be wrong. I'm not sure on this count.

Comment: Looks like a pat answer.

Answer (score 6):

It helps if you're familiar with the expression *pat answer*. According to [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pat+answer), a *pat answer* is one that is **quick, easy, simplified, or evasive**. NOAD defines it as **simple and somewhat glib or unconvincing**.

So, while it could mean the answer was *apt* and *perfectly timed* (as others have suggested), it could just as well mean the answer was simple, and didn't provide a lot of extra information.

Either way, *pat came the reply* is a very unusual way to phrase it. Normally, I think you'd find something like: *He gave a pat reply: "Sir, I did not fast for one day."*

It may be worth noting that "I did not fast for one day" could be interpreted in two ways:

- I fasted for more than one day.
- I fasted for zero days.

Because the answer is ambiguous, it could be considered a pat answer, in that it is both simple and evasive.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. OED agrees: "to be able to recite or perform readily and faultlessly from memory; (also, depreciatively) to repeat glibly, to parrot" and "Hence: (with negative connotation) glib, facile, unconsidered." Not so much that the replies are well-rehearsed or convenient, but more that they were glib, as in without thought.

Answer (score 3):

[***Pat***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pat) as an **adverb** means:

> At exactly the **right moment** or in the right way; very **conveniently** or
>   **opportunely**:

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

In your examples, the adverb **opportunely** or **conveniently** is the closest adverb to the meaning of **pat**.

> Emperor Bahadur Shah Zafar asked him:
>
> "Mirza, kitne rozey rakhkhey?" ("Mirza, how many days did you fast?")
>
> Opportunely or conveniently (**as if he/she were waiting for this question or he/she knew the Emperor would ask this question**) came the reply : "Bas huzoor, ek nahin rakhkha" ("Sir, I did not
>   fast for one day")

According to [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pat), the word started to be used **as an adverb** before it was used as an adjective meaning:

> "aptly, suitably, at the right time," 1570s, perhaps from pat (adj.)
>   in sense of "that which hits the mark," a special use from pat (n.) in
>   sense of "a hitting" of the mark. **The modern adjective is 1630s, from
>   the adverb**.